# Make Java IO Socket listen just like a ServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets, io

I'm doing a financial messaging integration as follows:

1. A server has an interface listening for requests from a client socket on a specific IP and port
2. Server sends a response for every request, back to the client socket
3. Also, server sends requests to the same client socket

The following is working perfectly:

1. The client socket (Socket object of Java IO) successfully sends requests to the server interface
2. The client socket successfully receives response for every request

```
try {
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("example.com", 8888);    
    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
    output.write(data);
    output.flush();
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    // Read responses or new request from input
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The client socket is supposed to receive any request from the server - the same way it's receiving responses from the same sever. However, when a server initiates a request to the client socket, the request is never received. However, we can trace the traffic from the tcpdump on the client environment.

How can I make the client socket listen to requests from the server, and not just responses?

**Update**

It might help to clarify something on this integration:

a. The 'server' in this case is a third party system, with it's integration rules

b. My client socket posts message to the server (above)

c. My implementation listens to responses and requests from the third **party system server**, either by creating my own **server socket** (ruled out), or using the very **client socket** I'm sending with (the solution I was seeking)

Comment: your client is listening to any port for incoming requests?

Comment: You need to develop a protocol in which the client can distinguish between responses to its requests and new requests from the server. For example, the first byte of message from server to client might be a byte which, if 0, is a response, and if non-zero is a request. These protocols can get very elaborate depending on the application.

Comment: @RAJKUMAR if I got your question right, yes. If the bind port is 32111 -  which is set by the environment, the server sends to that port for both requests and responses. The sending port does not matter.

Comment: @JamesKPolk that is already there, the response is different from a new request, and there's logic to take care of that, just that I had omitted it for simplicity, but let me comment the code.

Comment: I got the answer, the solution is to create a separate server thread, that uses the same socket as the client socket. I'm going ahead to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common mistake, you are writing a message without writing "\n" (end line identifier) at the end so no messages will be read. To fix this use [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) with [println](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println(java.lang.String)).

That will send a line to the other socket.

Here is an example of a thread-per-client model of a server

```java
//create a new server socket with the port as a parameter, this will bind it to the specified port: 6000
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6000);
        System.out.println("Binded");
        //create a while loop accepting sockets
        while(true)
        {
            //accept a socket
            Socket client = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Client has connected");
            //create a new thread for this socket
            new Thread(() ->
            {
                try
                {
                    /*
                    create a print writer so you can write a line, not only a message like BufferedWriter does,
                    if for some reason you still want to use BufferedWriter use
                    writer.write(message + "\n");
                     */
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
                    //Create a new reader
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                    System.out.println("Waiting for requests...");
                    //create a while loop reading requests (lines)
                    String request;
                    while((request = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Received message: " + request);
                        //here find the correct response and return it, I just sent a message, replace it with the correct response
                        writer.println("Hello there! How are you today?");
                        //flush, flushing will write the data to the client
                        writer.flush();
                    }
                } catch(IOException e)
                {
                    //print an exception if it occurred, if an exception occurrs its most likely just a disconnection exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();
        }
```

and here is an example of a client

```java
//connect to the server at "localhost" on port 6000
        Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 6000);
        System.out.println("Connected");
        /*
        create a print writer so you can write a line, not only a message like BufferedWriter does,
        if for some reason you still want to use BufferedWriter use
        writer.write(message + "\n");
        */
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
        //Create a new reader
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        //write a request
        writer.println("Hi there!");
        //flush, flushing will write the data to the server
        writer.flush();
        System.out.println("Written");
        System.out.println("Waiting for responses...");
        //create a while loop reading responses (lines)
        //you may want to do this while loop in another thread
        String response;
        while((response = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Received response: " + response);
        }
```

Also if this is involved with financial information I recommend using [TLS (SSL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

You don't have to worry Java already has it implemented and has made it easy to use, here is an example of a server

```java
//create a new SSL server socket with the port as a parameter, this will bind it to the specified port: 6000
        //you create it by getting the default SSLServerSocketFactory which will create a new SSLServerSocket
        //you need to cast it since it actually returns ServerSocket but SSLServerSocket extends ServerSocket and this returns SSLServerSocket so it is safe
        SSLServerSocket server = (SSLServerSocket) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(6000);
        System.out.println("Binded");
        //set the enabled ciphersuites, until you buy a certificate set only to ciphersuites with "anon" more info on ciphersuites on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_suite
        server.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[]{"TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"});
        //create a while loop accepting sockets
        while(true)
        {
            //accept a socket a SSLSocket
            SSLSocket client = (SSLSocket) server.accept();
            System.out.println("Client has connected");
            //create a new thread for this socket
            new Thread(() ->
            {
                try
                {
                    //begin a handshake more info about handshakes in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/sy10660_.htm
                    client.startHandshake();
                    /*
                    create a print writer so you can write a line, not only a message like BufferedWriter does,
                    if for some reason you still want to use BufferedWriter use
                    writer.write(message + "\n");
                     */
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
                    //Create a new reader
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                    System.out.println("Waiting for requests...");
                    //create a while loop reading requests (lines)
                    String request;
                    while((request = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Received message: " + request);
                        //here find the correct response and return it, I just sent a message, replace it with the correct response
                        writer.println("Hello there! How are you today?");
                        //flush, flushing will write the data to the client
                        writer.flush();
                    }
                } catch(IOException e)
                {
                    //print an exception if it occurred, if an exception occurrs its most likely just a disconnection exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();
        }
```

And here is an example of a client

```java
//connect to the server at "localhost" on port 6000
        //you create a SSLSocket by getting the default SSLSocketFactory which will create a new SSLSocket
        //you need to cast it since it actually returns Socket but SSLSocket extends Socket and this returns SSLSocket so it is safe
        SSLSocket client = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket("localhost", 6000);
        System.out.println("Connected");
        //set the enabled ciphersuites to everything supported so the server can decide the ciphersuite, you can modify this to specified ciphersuites
        client.setEnabledCipherSuites(client.getSupportedCipherSuites());
        //begin a handshake more info about handshakes in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/sy10660_.htm
        client.startHandshake();
        /*
        create a print writer so you can write a line, not only a message like BufferedWriter does,
        if for some reason you still want to use BufferedWriter use
        writer.write(message + "\n");
        */
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
        //Create a new reader
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        //write a request
        writer.println("Hi there!");
        //flush, flushing will write the data to the server
        writer.flush();
        System.out.println("Written");
        System.out.println("Waiting for responses...");
        //create a while loop reading responses (lines)
        //you may want to do this while loop in another thread
        String response;
        while((response = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Received response: " + response);
        }
```

Comment: Kindly read the question again; numbers 1, 2, 3 - you will realize that the server my client socket sends to - a third party system, will send the response back  *AND* a new request to my client socket. So creating a ServerSocket does not apply. My only wish is that you understand that.

Comment: a ServerSocket is used here just on the server-side (the host), to give you more information I decided to add it so you can understand sockets deeper. I needed to code it anyway to test the client code.